# Select an output column to be used for LIKE

Tags: database, t-sql, select, sql-like

I want to use **LIKE** to a column that is an output of my **CONVERT**, just like the code below.
But it is not working since the column I've selected doesn't belong to the view i've been using. Is there a way for me to do it this way? or shall i really create a new view instead?

```
SELECT 
[DESCRIPTION],
CONVERT(varchar, CAST([ITEM VALUE]*[QTY] AS money), 1) AS [TOTAL AMOUNT],
FROM vwItemList
WHERE [TOTAL AMOUNT] LIKE '%' + @targetItem + '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a sub query or repeat it since you cannot refer to an alias in the `WHERE`-clause

```
SELECT 
[DESCRIPTION],
CONVERT(varchar, CAST([ITEM VALUE]*[QTY] AS money), 1) AS [TOTAL AMOUNT],
FROM vwItemList
WHERE CONVERT(varchar, CAST([ITEM VALUE]*[QTY] AS money), 1) LIKE '%' + @targetItem + '%'
```

Another option, a `CTE` which is similar to a sub query:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [Description], 
           CONVERT(VARCHAR, Cast([Item value] * [Qty] AS MONEY), 1) AS [TOTAL AMOUNT], 
    FROM   Vwitemlist 
)
SELECT [Description],
       [TOTAL AMOUNT]
FROM   CTE 
WHERE  [TOTAL AMOUNT] LIKE '%' + @targetItem + '%'
```